# subreport is not displaying it is printing only the static text but not parameters?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created the subreport and mapped to main report but it is not displaying the text field expressions it is displaying only the heading and the amount is displaying null.Please suggest me as I am new to Ireport designs.

Main report:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="esr-design-40" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="16"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<scriptlet name="esrgenerator" class="dk.comtalk.billing.server.util.ESRGenerator"/>
<parameter name="printAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerProvince" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerPostalCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityLogo" class="java.io.File"/>
<parameter name="countryCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="balance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="carriedBalance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="totalWithTax" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="newStatusId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ravi Workspace\\Openbrm\\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\\resources\\designs\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select count(*) from payment_invoice p where p.invoice_id=$P{invoiceId};]]>
</queryString>
<field name="payment_count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<group name="invoice_total">
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<title>
    <band height="430">
        <image>
            <reportElement x="8" y="0" width="185" height="48" />
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityLogo}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="120" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]> </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="148" width="294" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="162" width="211" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="57" y="134" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="384" y="103" width="200" height="28" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[1. opomena za neizmireni racun]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="405" y="173" width="179" height="14" />
            <text><![CDATA[Wangen b. Brüttisellen, 13.12.2015]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="201" width="328" height="19" />
            <text><![CDATA[Postovani gospodine/postovana gospodjo,]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="220" width="544" height="35" />
            <text><![CDATA[Dozvolite da Vas podsetimo da je, po podacima naseg knjigovodstva od danasnjeg dana, sledeci telefonski racun jos otvoren:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="317" width="549" height="34" />
            <text><![CDATA[Ukoliko je Vasa uplata za ovde navedeni racun u medjuvremenu vec izvrsena, nemojte uzimati ovu opomenu u obzir. Ukoliko jos nije, molimo Vas da izvrsite uplatu izvrsite odmah.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="351" width="557" height="69" />
            <text><![CDATA[Imajte u vidu da se kod opomena, uz regularni racun, placa administrativna taksa za obradu u visini od Fr. 20.00. Ev.deaktivacija servisa se, takodje, naplacuje, dodatnih Fr. 20.00. Molimo Vas stoga za postovanje nasih rokova uplate.

  Najlepse hvala.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="36" y="268" width="559" height="60" />
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="117">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="36" y="101" width="576" height="16" />
            <text><![CDATA[Symphonica AG | Hegnaustrasse 17 | 8602 Wangen b. Brüttisellen | Telefon 0840 988 988 | Fax 043 536 05 43]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="35" y="8" width="243" height="26" />
            <text><![CDATA[S postovanjem,
     BALKATEL | Symphonica A.D.]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<summary>
    <band height="294">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="56" width="123" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="68" width="153" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="81" width="226" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityPostalCode}+ " " + $P{entityCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="5" y="26" width="100" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[6301 Zug]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="179" y="26" width="100" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[6301 Zug]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="56" width="123" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="68" width="149" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="179" y="81" width="226" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityPostalCode}+ " " + $P{entityCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="97" y="110" width="100" height="14" />
            <text><![CDATA[01-2653-5]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="272" y="110" width="100" height="16" />
            <text><![CDATA[01-2653-5]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="169" y="236" width="640" height="30" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="13"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.generateCodeline($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1],"01",">","971786","+","0126535",">",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="132" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="144" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="158" width="294" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="193" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="205" width="181" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="218" width="251" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{customerPostalCode}+ " " + $P{customerCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="172" width="211" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="230" width="194" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{countryCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="353" y="92" width="424" height="19" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.getReferenceNumber("971786",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="8" y="172" width="186" height="16" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.getReferenceNumber("971786",$P{invoiceId})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="132" y="142" width="47" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[1])]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="301" y="142" width="40" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[1])]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="2" y="142" width="105" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[0]).trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="173" y="142" width="105" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11"/>
             </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression> <![CDATA[$P{esrgenerator_SCRIPTLET}.splitAmount($P{printAmount}.split("\\s+")[1].split("\\.")[0]).trim()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
 </summary>
 </jasperReport>
```

subreport.jrxml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="70" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="newStatusId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="printAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="balance" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="30">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="2" y="14" width="65" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Racun od]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="83" y="14" width="65" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nacin pl.]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="164" y="14" width="85" height="14" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Broj racuna]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="262" y="14" width="85" height="14" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Rok istekao]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="375" y="14" width="48" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Iznos]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="437" y="14" width="58" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Otvoreno]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="504" y="14" width="52" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Step.nap]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="19">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="495" y="3" width="34" height="12" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$P{newStatusId}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="356" y="3" width="67" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{printAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="262" y="3" width="100" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceDueDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="164" y="3" width="75" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$P{invoiceId}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="83" y="3" width="77" height="14" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Racun]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="2" y="3" width="75" height="14" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoiceDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="423" y="2" width="67" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{printAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<summary>
    <band height="20">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="266" y="0" width="163" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Ukupno CHF. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="423" y="0" width="67" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{printAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6AvX.png)

now I am printing the invoice like this in the next line i need to print the details with multiple invoices and i need to sum all those and print the total.

Comment: From what I can see you are calling the subreport correctly, however its not a good idea to use $F{} in summary band (the dataset is at the end) and I can't see you passing $P{balance} nor $P{newStatusId}

Comment: if I print the InvoiceId then I will test other parameters.In which band we need to use the $F{}.Please suggest me.It is very important for me.

Comment: I guess you need to [edit] the question to display current output better, remember we do not have your data and as question is there is a lot guessing involved.

Comment: to debug put the $P{invoiceId} in columHeader (to see the value that is passed), test the query with that value so you verify that your sql has result.

Comment: I had tested the query by giving the invoiceId in the place of $P{invoiceId}.It is getting the output

Comment: You tested setting fixed value in jrxml or you have tested in query browser? The $F{} should normally only be used in detail band

Comment: select p.amount as paid_amount,due_date as invoice_due_date from payment_invoice p join invoice i on i.id=p.invoice_id join base_user b on b.id=user_id join contact co on b.id=co.user_id  where p.invoice_id=23107 ;In my sql workbench I have tested by using this query

Comment: It displayed the data but when I use in jrxml it is not showing any data

Comment: Ok so start debugging, example you can remove  $P{invoiceId} form your subreport query and set it fixed to 23107 (to check that your parameter is arriving correctly.

Comment: In your subreport you are using status_id = 27 in where clause . Are you sure that is correct with your invoiceId. and in above sql you are not testing with status_id.  Can you plesae check this

select p.amount as paid_amount,due_date as invoice_due_date from payment_invoice p join invoice i on i.id=p.invoice_id join base_user b on b.id=user_id join contact co on b.id=co.user_id where p.invoice_id=23107 and status_id = 27;

Comment: the InvoiceId is displayed but i need to get list of InvoiceId's to be print.Can you please suggest me how to print the list of InvoiceIds.

Comment: @Fahad Anjum plese reply me it is very important for me.

Comment: Actually , your report is working on one invoice id at the time. I am not sure why you want multiple invoice id in report.  

Let me correct if i am wrong 
Do you want to generate multiple invoice at the same time ? or can you give me an example how your data is and how you want with an image as we do not have any database.

Comment: yes I need to print multiple invoices at the same time.

Comment: right now , you are able to generate only invoice at time. is that correct

Comment: yes right now I can generate only one invoice.

Comment: Step: 
1) Create one new jrxml .
2) Use sql which actually generates all values that is required in your current jrxml. 
I am sure you are having invoice related all information.

in your sql : invoiceid, customerid, entityName , entityAddress, entitypostal etc 
Note: sql should have all columns that you are using in current jrxml as a parameter.

3) delete all bands except detail band height of that band is equal to current jrxml height.

Comment: Can't we do with the subreport? or by creating the list of all invoiceIds and make it as a string can't we pass like that

Comment: Instead of creating single select invoice id, create a multiselect only in your main jrxml. 

select count(*) from payment_invoice p where $X{IN, p.invoice_id, invoiceId }
group by p.invoice_id ;

Now use detail band only and use the same jrxml.

Comment: ok can we create a object and pass all those parameters and pass the object to jasper.Now I am sending individually but I need to send in a object all those parameters.Please suggest me.

Comment: Can you please tell your requirement ? like How end user will run this report. what parameters he can select. right now he has to select more than 15 parameters in order to generate single invoice. If you can tell me what is end user parameter than i can suggest in more better way

Comment: actually I am using printAmount,InvoiceDate,invoiceDueDate,invoiceId to print in the subreport.As far I have done with individual parameters but now I need to send this parameters in a object.

Comment: @FahadAnjum please reply me.It is very important for me.